# What is /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-5 for?

Tags: rkhunter

I get those messages on `rkhunter --check --rwo`:

```
     /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-5-13: data
     /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-5-1000: data
     /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-5: data
```

I can ignore them in `/etc/rkhunter.conf` with

```
ALLOWDEVFILE=/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-5
ALLOWDEVFILE=/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-5-1000
ALLOWDEVFILE=/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-5-13
```

But I'd rather first understand the reasons.

Which process is creating them and what for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files are created by LTTng UST (User-Space Tracer). More specifically, those files are used in a rendez-vous mechanism between the user-space tracer and the lttng session daemon. See http://lttng.org for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that those files are used for phone emulation (with virtualisation software like VM). I had the same result and files

Answer (score 0):

I opened a defect for this with the project to see what they say about it.

https://bugs.lttng.org/issues/1143